# Ubuntu upgrade 14.04 > 16.04.1 failed

Tags: upgrade

I received an option to download 16.04.1 on my Thinkpad-T410 from 14.04.

I proceeded with the upgrade and checked it on regular intervals as it was installing packages. On my last check the screen was blank and the laptop was in a shutdown state. I hit the power on button and was presented with console messages as the laptop was booting up and presented with the following:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS ThinkPad-T410 tty1

ThinkPad-T410 login: <entered my login id>
Password: <entered my password>
Last login: Sun Jul 31 21:48:04 BST 2016 on tty1
E: Error BrokenCount > 0run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 255
mother@ThinkPad-T410: $
```

How do I proceed to resolve this error?